# How to make it so that two responsive fluid images change their size proportional and always remain on the same height?

Tags: css, flexbox, materialize

I'm using materialize.css and I have a container with 3 divs there: text, one image and the second one. Those images have responsive-img class from  materialize.css which makes them fluid (max-width: 100% and height: auto). When I change the screen size, the image on the right goes down unfortunately  That's how it looks:
[image]

That's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
          <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed orem ipsum dolor  consetetursit amet, sadipscing elitr, sed orem consetetur sadipscing elitr.
          </p>
          <p class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed orem ipsum dolor  consetetursit amet, sadipscing elitr, sed orem consetetur sadipscing elitr.
          </p>
          <div>
          <img class="responsive-img" src="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m6 l6">
          <div>
          <img class="responsive-img" src="">
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I just try to do that this way that the both images are always on the same height while changing like here:
[image]

Would be happy if you could help me!
Thanks

Comment: This is not possible in a responsive way because the images do not have the same height/width ratio. This is only possible in a responsive way if the images on a row has the same ratio, for example image1 is 900x600 (3:2) and image2 is 600x400 (also 3:2).

Comment: By giving a `float` (left or right) and a `width:50%` to these images, the text will flow around the images. Cannot give more info without knowing other classes (s12 m6 l6) and other custom css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What could be possible solution for this case? Maybe using grid, I saw an example somewhere, where the similar layout works, the images are just getting smaller or bigger and remain on the same height on the bottom...

Comment: Did not test this. First remove the div around the image. Then ty one of these:
`class="col d-flex s12 m6 l6 justify-content-end"` or `class="col d-flex s12 m6 l6 align-items-end"`

Comment: Youre genius! Thanks! class="col d-flex s12 m6 l6 align-items-end worked out :)

Comment: Top. Success with your website.